# I've got some errors of type "expected primary-expression before 'int' "in my main function. What's wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14;

void ReadinputData(int& a, int& b){

cout << " Give me the height of the Cylinder: ";
cin >> a ;
cout << " Give me the radious of its base: ";
cin >> b ;

}


void ComputetheResults(int a,int b,int &x,int &y){

x= 2*PI*b*a;
y= PI*a*b*b;

}

void DisplayAnswers(int a, int b){

cout<< "the surface are of the cylinder is: "<< a<< endl;
cout<< "the volume of the cylinder is: "<< b << endl;

}


int main()
{
int h,r,A,V;
h=0;
r=0;
A=0;
V=0;
ReadinputData(int h, int r);
ComputetheResults(int h,int r,int &A,int &V);
DisplayAnswers(int A,int V);

}
```

The errors are the following:

-------------- Build: Debug in eeee ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:39:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:39:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:40:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:40:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:40:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:40:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:41:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/home/vaios/Desktop/ertt/eeeeee/eeee/main.cpp:41:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
8 errors, 0 warnings

Comment: You should be using `float`s or `double`s, not `int`s, for this sort of math. If you use `int`s, you'll have very imprecise results. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to re-declare the data-types of an argument when calling a function.  So change:

```
ReadinputData(int h, int r);
ComputetheResults(int h,int r,int &A,int &V);
DisplayAnswers(int A,int V);
```

To simply:

```
ReadinputData(h, r);
ComputetheResults(h, r, A, V);
DisplayAnswers(A, V);
```

As it stands right now with your current un-corrected code, you're basically re-declaring the function without a valid return type inside of `main` rather than calling the function with the appropriate arguments.  That's going to throw a compiler error.

Comment: why does it give a compile error? isn't it simple re-declaration?

Comment: Declaring a function inside another function is not a feature supported by `g++` or other C++ compilers, nor is there a requirement to support that in the C++03 standard.  It is a feature supported by `gcc`, but only as a C-language extension (i.e., it's not supported by the ISO C-standard, but they didn't say you *can't* do it, so the implementers of the `gcc` compiler have added it as a non-standard C-language extension).

Comment: @Ali - It would have been a declaration if the functions had had a return type. Now it is just wrong.

Comment: @Jason - *Declaring* a function is ok. *Defining* one inside another is a gcc extension.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for clearing that up ... I've also updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the types of a function's arguments when calling it.

In other words, line 39 should read

```
Readinputdata(h, r);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you calling a function don't specify argument types.

```
ReadinputData(h, r);
```